# Both libc.so.6 and libc.so exist in rootfs

Tags: yocto, glibc, libc, rootfs

I used Yocto to generated my rootfs, and a wired thing happened, both libc.so.6 and libc.so existing in my rootfs (/usr/lib/libc.so and /lib/libc.so.6). But they are different objects (not linking to a single object), that will cause my compiling with Yocto sdk failed.

I know my libc.so is installed along with libsqlite3-dev installed, but I don't know which recipe that really generates libc.so.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libc.so` is a *linker script*, a small text file which looks like this (lines wrapped here for readability):

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP (
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 )
)
```

It instructs the link editor (`ld`, which is invoked while linking during build, i.e., not the dynamic linker) to look for symbols first in `libc.so.6`, a shared object, then in `libc_nonshared.a` if it cannot find it, and finally in the dynamic loader, `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`).  This is used to implement certain features, for example in newer versions of glibc, the caller-senitive function `pthread_atfork` (which must be linked statically, so it is placed in `libc_nonshared.a` and not `libc.so.6`).  The linker script is usually invoked implicitly by the `gcc` or `g++` commands, but occasionally, you will see command lines which contain `-lc`, and those pick up the `libc.so` script (when linking dynamically).

The linker script is only used at build time.  If you image contains development libraries such as `libsqlite3-dev`, it is necessary to include `libc6-dev` (or whatever the package is called that provides the `libc.so` linker script) because `libsqlite3-dev` is not usable for linking new programs and shared objects without glibc.

Comment: Thanks. but libc.so is already been installed to rootfs /usr/lib. And I checked it, /* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) ). It is like what you said. But when I used sdk to compile my application, it still displays libc.so.6 not found.

Comment: Thanks very much, you are correct. libc.so instructs to find libc.so.6 in /lib but my real ld is topdir/lib, that cause libc.so.6 not found. So I have to remove topdir.